# Backbone collection, get specific attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, console.log

I've set an attribute `currentPage` on my Backbone collection, however I seem to not be able to log it specifically.

```
    onRender: function () {
        App.log('this.collection.currentPage onRender')
        App.log(this.collection)
        App.log(this.collection.accountID)
        App.log(this.collection.currentPage)
        App.log(this.collection.get('currentPage'))

    }
```

I do the fetch then show, and within onRender, the following console log is produced

[image: console log of collection]

where `this.collection.currentPage` and `this.collection.get('currentPage')` are `undefined` even though I can see currentPage as a defined ("2") attribute in the log output of `this.collection`. `this.collection.accountID` is working how I expected `currentPage` to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am setting the attribute on the `success` of `.fetch` because the data is returned in the response headers. Something like this,

```
getAccountSegments: function (accountID) {
    var accountSegmentsCollection = new Entities.Collections.AccountSegmentCollection({
        accountID: accountID
    });

    accountSegmentsCollection.fetch({
        success: function (collection, response, options) {
            collection.currentPage = options.xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Current-Page');
        }
    });

    return accountSegmentsCollection;
},
```

Someone stated below that I am not allowed to set attributes on the collection (except by way of the constructor, but that's before the fetch). So how else could I get this response header data into my view?

Comment: When/Where are you setting the attribute..? Maybe you're setting it after render. How do we know..? Share the relevant code.

Comment: @TJ See my edit, I set it after `.fetch`. The weird part is that I see currentPage logged with the collection correctly in onRender but not when I log currentPage directly.

Comment: Still it is not clear in which order `onRender` and `fetch` is called. When/how are you calling `getAccountSegments` and `onRender`..? Are you sure render happens after fecth..?

Answer (score 0):

Collections in backbone js do not allow you to set attributes.
The best way to store meta information in a backbone collection is through plain javascript object.

For example:

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: myModel,

    metaInfo: {
      currentPage: "2"
    }
});
```

Then you can get the current page in your view using `this.collection.metaInfo.currentPage`

Comment: The problem here is that `metaInfo` will be attached to the collection prototype and thus shared by all instances, I think you'd want to `this.metaInfo = { currentPage: '2' }` in the collection's `initialize` method instead.

Comment: But isn't the meta information should be accessible by all instances ?

Comment: The problem persists because I am trying to set `currentPage` on the `success` of `.fetch`. The server returns paginated data with a `X-Current-Page` header. On success I do `collection.metaInfo.currentPage = options.xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Current-Page');` and it does not set correctly. It is still undefined (or, by your suggestion, set to a default on the collection constructor) when I get to my view. How else could I get this header data into my view?

Comment: I am attempting to create a "X of Y Items" label. So I similarly have a `collection.metaInfo.totalCount = options.xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Count');` header to pass.

Comment: Yes but it probably shouldn't be on the prototype: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yxv37qhz/

Answer (score 0):

`get` in this context is a little confusing. In Backbone Models have attributes, but collections do not, this means that `get` on a collection is different from `get` on a model.

`get` on a model retrieves an attribute, while on a collection it will return a model (by id). You could extend your collection to have attribute getters and setters:

```
var pageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    getAttribute: function(attr) {
        return this.attributes?this.attributes[attr]:null;
    },
    setAttribute: function(attr,val){
        this.attributes = this.attributes || {};
        this.attributes[attr] = val;
    }
});
```

You could then set your currentPage attribute:

```
pageCollection.setAttribute('currentPage', 'myPage');
```

And retrieve it:

```
App.log(pageCollection.getAttribute('currentPage');
```

Which should give you the functionality you are after.